# Convergence and Limit of the infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

How can I find the limit of the series

$$
\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(c+2^{t-1})}{2^t} \;\;\text{where}\; c > 0
$$

Since the terms are positive, and I have an intuition that $a_{n-1} \geq a_n$, the series converge to a limit point.

I tried to analytically show that the terms are decreasing, as below

$$
\frac{\ln(c+2^{n-1})}{2^n} \leq \frac{\ln(2^{n-1}+2^{n-1})}{2^n} \leq \frac{\ln 2}{2^{n-1}}
$$

But I am not sure about the selection of the upper bound for the constant $c$.  How can I show that the series converge and find the limit of it ?

Comment: Are you after a proof of the convergence of the series or after the exact value of its sum? (Unrelated: What do you call $a_n$?)

Comment: Seems pretty hard to find the sum. Differentiating w.r.t. $a$ does not yield promising result by WolframAlpha…

Comment: @Did  I am interested in the exact value of the limit of the series.  I did not understand the part "What do you call $a_n$". I used $a_n$ to denote the $n^{th}$ term in the partial sum of the series.

Comment: If $\;a_n\;$ for you is the series' general addend, as it is usually denoted, then it is false that if $\;\{a_n\}\;$ is positive and monotone descending the series $\;\sum a_n\;$ converges...

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes true. It guarantees that the alternating sign series converges right ?.  As Fred shown below, we can make use of the fact that the series converges as per comparison test.

Comment: "I used an to denote the nth term in the partial sum of the series" Then **say so in the question**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. As regards convergence note that
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\ln(c+2^{n})}{2^{n+1}}\cdot \frac{2^n}{\ln(c+2^{n-1})}=
\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{\ln(c+2^{n})}{\ln(c+2^{n-1})}\sim \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{n\ln(2)}{(n-1)\ln(2)}\to \frac{1}{2}$$
where $a_n=\dfrac{\ln(c+2^{n-1})}{2^n}>0$. What may we conclude?

Comment: this indicates that the limit is less than $\frac{1}{2}$, right ?.  Is it tight or can we find the exact value ?

Comment: @Shew The limit of the ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is eaxactly $1/2$.

Answer (score 3):

There is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $a \le 2^n$ for all $n>N$. Thus

$0 \le a_n:=\frac{\ln(a+2^{n-1})}{2^n} \leq \frac{\ln(2^{n-1}+2^{n-1})}{2^n} =n\frac{\ln 2}{2^{n}}=:b_n$ for all $n>N$.

The ratio test shows that $ \sum b_n$ is convergent, hence $\sum a_n$ is convergent.